# django cbv not sending mails

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

i am trying to send mail entered in a form which i have in bottom of my html but it does not send mail and does not give errors also

my view:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'homepage.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'post':
            message = request.POST['message']
            name = request.POST['name']
            email = request.POST['email']

            send_mail('contact form', message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['******@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

my html form:

```
<form method="post" action={% url 'homepage' %}>
             {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter First Name"/><br>

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/><br>
                <input type="textarea" name="message" placeholder="How can we help you?"/><br>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'homepage.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = request.POST['message']
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']

        send_mail('contact form', message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['******@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

also I would use something like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms because is more like a django way of doing it.

Comment: hey thanks it works now but can you help on how can i get message name and email all emailed to me

Comment: you have two approachs to do that:

1) saving in a model after call send_mail, saving these three fields, then you will query against that model.
2) read emails with python, this post would help: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python